# How to finish specific activity from A,B,C, D, E?

Tags: android

I have above activities.  The flow is A - B, B- C, C- D, D- E.
If on activity E if user press back then it should go to directly on activity B.
But in that reverse flow should work. Means D-C, C- B.

Answer (score 1):

Add `onActivityResult` on each activity classes. If E finished D's `onActivityResult` will be get called there you can again finish your D class and so on. In this way you can handle what ever you want. For getting `onActivityResult` you need to start you activity by calling `startActivityForResult` with request code.
For you reference : [Getting a Result from an activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Comment: can you explain me detail how to onActivityResult.

Answer (score 0):

Use `finish()` method when you send intent to other activity. When your `startActivity` is call use `finish()` after this statement. `finish()` method finished activity from stack. If you want to display previous activity then remove `finish()` method when you send `Intent`.

Comment: its not working. Because on activity C start Activity is call use finish() then it goes on activity D. on back pressed from D activity C is not visible.

Comment: Remove finish() from Activity c.  check edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Call like this dude :)

call all activity like this

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
```

but when u press back from E then call this in back button on click

```
 Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
 finish();
```

i.e only this particualr E activity not remain in stack all other will be present like reverse flow should work. Means D-C, C- B.

Comment: From Second Activity if user pressed back button then FirstActivity is remaining in stack?

Comment: read my question, If user pressed back from activity D then activity must be remain.

Comment: Still not correct, if back is pressed in Activity E, it opens B and closes E, but when back is pressed afterwards, B will close and user will go back to D.

Comment: yes exactly u also want to go from here to D-C, C- B. look ur ans dude be clear what u want to do

Comment: just follow the thumb rule if u write finish with intent that will not remain in stack that's it ohk :) follow and do with thumb rule never copy code just apply ur own login i told u the logic olz apply

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Other way is

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

and other way is adding

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

in your manifest as describe here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist

Answer (score 0):

Just startActivity like

```
        Intent i = new Intent(currentActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        currentActivity.finish();
```

If you want to kill background running Activities,then use

```
 try
    {
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("CLOSE_ALL");
         broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                ActivityName.this.finish();
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
```